# google-play-service_lib missing in android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was installed `google play services` in **sdk manager**. After that i try to import google-play-services lib file from sdk/extra/ folder but google folder is missing.

I tried:

1.Restarted Eclipse

2.Clean all the project

3.Exit and open the Eclipse

Comment: i dont know why they given negative vote instance of answer

Comment: thay given negative vote my answer too :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]the path is  .../sdk/extra/google/google-play-services. Check it again plz

UPDATE: 
  see carefull the sdk path, make sure your Google play service is Installed.

Comment: +1 thanks but  i tried to open in sdk/extra/google/google-play-service path but google folder itself missing

Comment: When I am new in Android, I used 2 SDK folders, so sometimes I got problem by update in 1 folder, but try to open other folder :D. Make sure you use 'exactly' SDK foler. If's not, try to create new folder with name 'google' and go to SDK Manager, delete GooglePlayService package and install again.... 
 I can not guess which cause your problem, sr....

Comment: i dnt know. i get a google-play-service lib file from chat.stackoverflow.com